# Odds to probabilty and back- I am not getting same value!

Tags: probability, odds

I am using following formulae to convert between odds and probability:

```
probability = odds / (1+odds)

odds = probability / (1-probability)
```

I am doing following calculations:

```
initial odds = 40 : 1

probability = 40 / (40+1) = 40/41 = 0.98
```

Converting back to odds:

```
odds = 0.98/ (1-0.98)  = 98/2 = 49
```

Where is the fallacy? Why am I not getting 40 again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
probability = 40/41 = 0.975609

odds = 0.975609/(1-0.975609) = 39.9987
```

The mistake is in the number of decimal places. Allowing for more decimal places will result in a more accurate solution.

Comment: Ok. Stupid mistake. But makes a point that accuracy can be very important.